# display json data with 5 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, arraylist

I have the following json data which is returned from PHP function.
I can add more IPs to functions and display the data with `var_dump`.
but I want to display the data as html table list.

I have tried many solutions, but nothing is working for me..

I'd be grateful if someone could help me display the data as HTML table.
thanks in advance..

here is the JSON:

```
{
    "103.46.233.22:83":
    {
        "allowed":["get","post","cookie","referer","user_agent"],
        "disallowed":[],
        "proxy_level":"transparent",
        "info":
        {
            "url":"http:\/\/test.com\/ping.php?q=query",
            "content_type":"text\/html; charset=UTF-8",
            "http_code":200,
            "header_size":385,
            "request_size":318,
            "filetime":-1,
            "ssl_verify_result":0,
            "redirect_count":0,
            "total_time":1.547,
            "namelookup_time":1.0e-6,
            "connect_time":0.328,
            "pretransfer_time":0.328,
            "size_upload":143,
            "size_download":127,
            "speed_download":82,
            "speed_upload":92,
            "download_content_length":-1,
            "upload_content_length":143,
            "starttransfer_time":0.328,
            "redirect_time":0,
            "redirect_url":"",
            "primary_ip":"103.46.233.22",
            "certinfo":[],
            "primary_port":83,
            "local_ip":"172.20.0.250",
            "local_port":52594
        }
    },
    "106.233.22.13:8080":
    {
        "allowed":["get","post","cookie","referer","user_agent"],
        "disallowed":[],
        "proxy_level":"transparent",
        "info":
        {
            "url":"http:\/\/test.com\/ping.php?q=query",
            "content_type":"text\/html; charset=UTF-8",
            "http_code":200,
            "header_size":385,
            "request_size":318,
            "filetime":-1,
            "ssl_verify_result":0,
            "redirect_count":0,
            "total_time":1.547,
            "namelookup_time":1.0e-6,
            "connect_time":0.328,
            "pretransfer_time":0.328,
            "size_upload":143,
            "size_download":127,
            "speed_download":82,
            "speed_upload":92,
            "download_content_length":-1,
            "upload_content_length":143,
            "starttransfer_time":0.328,
            "redirect_time":0,
            "redirect_url":"",
            "primary_ip":"106.233.22.13",
            "certinfo":[],
            "primary_port":8080,
            "local_ip":"172.20.0.250",
            "local_port":52594
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _i want to display the data as html table list..._ Post your attempts please.. Hint: `json_decode` could be your friend

Comment: Its not a code writing service

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate the JSON string you got there by converting it into an object or array.

E.g.:

```
$array = json_decode(' { "103.46.233.22:83": []}', true);
```

Then you can iterate the array to output your HTML. See the [PHP documentation for json_encode](https://php.net/json_decode).

For this to work, you will need to have the PHP extension "json" installed and activated.